# Second derivative of discrete function

Tags: sequences-and-series, finite-differences

Given function $y[n]$ what is the best way to define the second derivative?

Some background to the question: in linear systems we often sample a continuous signal to a discrete one with sample rate of $T_s$, and then use Z-transform to find the output. So, given a system defined by a second derivative, how to transform it?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: so, is it safe to say that y''[n]= (y[n+1]-2y[n] +y[n])/Ts^2  ?

Comment: @user107761 The last term should be $+y[n - 1]$.

Comment: @user107761 is $T_s$ a frequency or an interval? If it's the interval between samples, then you've got it right. If it's the frequency, you need to multiply by $T_s^2$ instead of dividing. Also, the last term should be $y[n-1]$

Comment: yea.. n-1 in the last one...

Comment: Check it like an engineer.  Pick an arbitrary $X(t) = t^3$, $T_s = 2$, so $y = \{0, 8, 64, 512,...\}$.  $X''(t) = 6t$, so $y'' = \{0, 12, 24, 36, 48...\}$.  Does your relation hold?  Do you think there is any chance you can eliminate $X$ from the relationship between $y$ and $y''$?

Comment: I edited the question. In the future, please use uppercase letters when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There is no even first derivative if the function is no continuous.

The mathematically consistent derivative(s) of a piecewise-constant function is proposed within theory of generalized functions (not sure about right translation of the term into english) where one get delta-function as a derivative of Heaviside step function.

Nevertheless within numerical schemes for solving problems PDE one uses such a presentation
$$y'_{n}=(y_{n+1}-y_{n-1})/(2h) \approx (y_{n+1}-y_{n})/h \approx (y_{n}-y_{n-1})/h$$
and
$$y''_{n}=(y'_{n+1}-y'_{n-1})/(2h)=( (y_{n+2}-y_{n})/(2h) -  (y_{n}-y_{n-2})/(2h))/(2h) =
(y_{n+2}+y_{n-2}-2y_{n})/(4h^2)$$
or with some notes write it as 
$$ y''_{n}=(y_{n+1}+y_{n-1}-2*y_{n})/(h^2)$$